# React-Native-Camera video recording with 60 frames?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-camera

I'm a beginner at React Native.
So far, I used React-Native-Camera to access a camera and record a video.
The problem is, the video I recorded is 30fps, but I want to record a video with 60fps.
Is there a way that I can change it to 60fps?
If it is not possible, then is there another library that I can try to make it 60fps?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

```
"@react-native-community/cameraroll": "4.1.2"
"react-native": "0.66.4",
"react-native-camera": "4.2.1",
"react-native-camera-hooks": "0.5.3"
```